# I am trying to convert my SQLite database into Postgres database, but I don't know how to convert name TEXT (32) NOT NULL

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE integrals (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   name TEXT (32) NOT NULL,
   ip TEXT (32),
   posx REAL NOT NULL,
   posy REAL NOT NULL,
   port INTEGER,
   image INT,
   zones TEXT,
   pass TEXT
);
```

This is my SQLite generated database, and I am trying to convert it, but I am very new to Postgres.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VARCHAR(32)` is working solution for this code.

Comment: No- PostgreSQL favours the TEXT type - add a CHECK  if you need to restrict the length! p.s. welcome to the forum!